# Gambits out of Nimzowitsch Defense

Tags: gambits, aggressive-play

What are some aggressive gambits that White could use out of the Nimzowitsch Defense? 1. e4 Nc6 d4 d5

Comment: If you want gambits 1 e4 Nc6 2 Nf3 might be more in keeping - you've still got things like the Scotch and the Evans amongst others available from this position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.e4 Nc6 2.d4 d5:

> 3.Nc3

scores best for White according to my database and it is the move I play.

3...dxe4

Your opponent can go into the French Defense with 3...e6, but this is not a good French with the N on c6 blocking the c-pawn.

4.d5 Ne5 is the most common.

5.Qd4 Ng6

Now White can consider Qxe4, h2-h4, f3... White has many aggressive options.

The safe 6.Qxe4 Nf6 7.Qa4+ Bd7 8.Qb3 continues to give Black problems.
The pawn sac offer of f2-f3 seems to have clear compensation based on the development advantage it gives.  But the problem with non-queen moves is that they allow Black to play e7-e5 which is close to equal.

> Alternatively 2.Nf3

a common line is 1.e4 Nc6 2.Nf3 offering Black to return to a standard opening with 2...e5.  If 2...d5 you get an odd Scandinvian/Center-counter.  Black usually plays 2...d6 and after 3.d4 Bg4 4.Bb5 a6 5.Bxc6 White scores better.

Answer (score 0):

There's 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.d5 as an interesting option, but I don't really think it's worth it as you will trade a slightly advantageous position for an equal/worse one and how many times are you gonna play 1.e4 Nc6 as White anyway? Your opponent will almost certainly be more prepared than you are!

Comment: I am not sure whether Black equalizes after 4.d5, but I am convinced that White, at least, is not worse.

Comment: Isn't this the mainline?

Comment: Maybe. I know nothing about 1.e4 Nc6. One more reason to avoid it!